# MVC 4.0 Passing data from form to another form without triggering validators

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass 3 form fields of data from form 1 to another View full form. Which means I want those 3 fields to be filled on form 2 in next view.

The problem I have is that after I submit the first form, the data is loaded in second form, but it triggers the validation, and boxes are red.

What would be the proper scenario?

This form is in View1.cshtml:

```
@model Presentation.Models.RegisterModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Register()))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LastName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="text-right" style="margin-top: 5px;">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn yellow" />
    </div>
}
```

Action for Register.cshtml view, where I want to append 3 fields from previous form, without triggering validation:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public virtual ActionResult Register(RegisterModel data)
        {
            return this.View(data);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using the same model for two different views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the ModelState:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public virtual ActionResult Register(RegisterModel data)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        return this.View(data);
    }
```